# Facebook has detected Believer isn't using a secure connection to transfer information

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-deployment, facebook-login

Well I am trying to add login and sign up with facebook functionality and when i click on login with facebook it takes me to facebook but shows an error such as
Facebook has detected Believer isn't using a secure connection to transfer information.
Until Believer updates its security settings, you won't be able to use Facebook to log into it.

I used comments for those lines which i add for social app. This code is from my project/settings.py

[image]

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap3',
    'accounts',


    'social_django', # <--adding social app

    ]


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware', #<--for social app 
]



TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'social_django.context_processors.backends',  # <-- Here
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect', # <-- Here
            
            ],
        },
    },
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'test'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'thanks'

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '1289678764728890'  # App ID
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '1c2a66c9c8116e4e2d97cb059db5d6a9'  # App Secret
```

Comment: show us your code and how do you use FB login, seems you are not using HTTPS on your page

Comment: I have added code. You can see and tell me if  I am wrong somewhere

Comment: It say that you need to update the security settings. Most likely it is talking about the Facebook Developer settings.

Comment: I updated them. but still didn't resolve this error. I have literally done a lot of search about this one but still couldn't solve out this.  Can you tell me solution with step by step approach. Like what settings I have to change on Facebook Developer.

Comment: You are redirecting to a http URL. Use a https link. And of course update the settings to allow the https URL.